# Regexp to match options which are delimited by spaces and also have spaces in their content

Tags: pcre

I am parsing a Wordpress shortcode and want to use PCRE mainly with a view to finally getting my head around it.

The following shortcode is one I wish to parse:

```
[testing att1='hello' att2='hello again' att3='£100']
```

My current regexp is:

```
\s?([a-z0-9_]*='[[:graph:]\£]*')\s?
```

This matches `att1` and `att3` but not `att2` due to the fact that it has whitespace in it. However when I amend my regexp to:

```
\s?([a-z0-9_]*='[[:graph:]\s\£]*')\s?   --- note the '\s' after [:graph:]
```

It matches from 'att1' to 'att3' in its entirety i.e. `att1='hello' att2='hello again' att3='£100'`. How do I match `att2` to include the whitespace and also preserve the fact that whitespace is a delimeter.

I think my issue is how I am stating how the group is terminated but unsure!

Comment: Maybe all you need is `\w+='[^']*'`? See https://regex101.com/r/F2naVc/1

Comment: Thank you. Please add as an answer and I'll accept it! One thing that has got me thinking though. Why do we have to say "Don't match the apostrophe" if it will be matched at the end anyway (assuming I've understood the syntax)

Comment: I do not understand what you mean, `'` at the end is matched with the last `'` in the pattern.

Comment: Yes - sorry! `[^']` is match anything apart from the apostrophe - not "don't match the apostrophe"(!). I've been looking at a lot of regex in the last 24 hours. After a while it sort of all blurs...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to match attributes with single-quoted arguments you can use

```php
\w+='[^']*'
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/F2naVc/1). *Details*:

- `\w+` - one or more letters, digits or underscores
- `='` - a `='` string
- `[^']*` - zero or more chars other than `'`
- `'` - a `'` char.